# How prevent Controls binding to Panel

Tags: c#, exception, panel

My form has a row of buttons along the top and another along the bottom. In order to improve the appearance, I put a Panel behind each of the two rows. This gives me the problem that I can no longer have a routine which can refer to any button. This is because I now need to include the name of the panel in the reference.

For instance, I have a routine which makes the button forecolor red when it gets the focus.

```
Internal void ButtonGotFocus()
{
    CurrentFieldName = this.ActiveControl.Name;
    this.Controls[CurrentFieldName].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
}
```

This routine now generates a null reference error for buttons which reside within a panel. I just want the panels to make my form look more presentable. I don't want to use them as a container. Can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's two panels, then you would have to check each panel:

```
if (Panel1.Controls.ContainsKey(CurrentFieldName)) {
  Panel1.Controls[CurrentFieldName].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
} else if (Panel2.Controls.ContainsKey(CurrentFieldName)) {
  Panel2.Controls[CurrentFieldName].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
}
```

Or you can create a Dictionary and reference the controls that way:

```
Dictionary<string, RadioButton> rboxes = new Dictionary<string, RadioButton>();
rboxes.Add(radioButton1.Name, radioButton1);
rboxes.Add(radioButton2.Name, radioButton2);
rboxes.Add(radioButton3.Name, radioButton3);
rboxes.Add(radioButton4.Name, radioButton4);

if (rboxes.ContainsKey(CurrentFieldName)) {
  rboxes[CurrentFieldName].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I like the first suggestion. However if i'm seeing this correctly, a Panel does not have the .ContainsKey() method. It has a .Contains() method which tests for a control rather than a ControlName. So I just realised my code can be simpler: this.ActiveControl.ForeColor= Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);

Comment: @IanPendlebury The Controls collection has the ContainsKey function.